# Apply Middleware auth to all routes except `editPostJob/id` in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to apply auth middleware to all routes except "editPostJob" route but it didnt work as there is an id in url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/editPostJob/1).
Everytime i tried to go to that link it redirects me to login page.

in controller I tried:

```
  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'confirm','editPostJob']);
    }
```

but it didnt work.
Any idea what should i do ?

thanks for any help.

Comment: is "editPostJob" a route name?

Comment: Route::get('editPostJob/{id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@yourMethod');

Comment: Route::get('editPostJob/{id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@yourMethod')->name('editPostJob');

Comment: Hi Anurat, I tried it but still the same , even i restart the server.

Comment: I was wrong, you only need method name, not route name. ->except(['index', 'confirm', 'yourMethod'])

Comment: This seems to go through but getting :Error
Call to a member function getAuthIdentifier() on null

Comment: public function yourMethod(Request $request) //select statement
    {
        $jobs = DB::table('jobs')->where('job_id', $request->id)->get();
        $is_read =strip_tags( $this->isLoggerOwnerOfPost($request->id));
        return view('editPostJob', compact('jobs'))->with('is_read', $is_read);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by doing:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'confirm', 'yourMethod']);
}

public function yourMethod(Request $request) //select statement
{
    if (\Auth::check() == false) {
        $is_read = "true";
    } else {
        $is_read = strip_tags($this->isLoggerOwnerOfPost($request->id));
    }
    $jobs = DB::table('jobs')->where('job_id', $request->id)->get();
    return view('editPostJob', compact('jobs'))->with('is_read', $is_read);
}
```

Thanks Anurat !